# How to save unlocked game levels during android memory clear

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When i play game then its workd perfectly, but when i clear memory of my android phone and again start game then it start from beginning and all level again locked.
Please help me how i can save my unlocked levels remain unlocked even when i clear android memory please help me thanks.
I have tried this but not working.

```
void Start () {
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("Level")) {
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
        releasedLevelStatic = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Level", releasedLevelStatic);

    }
}
public void ButtonNextLevel()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene (nextLevel);
    if(releasedLevelStatic <= releasedLevel){
        releasedLevelStatic = releasedLevel;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Level", releasedLevelStatic);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are use SharedPreferences am I correct? In that case you need online database so that even when you clear up your data in your phone the saved game is not deleted.

Comment: No no, its unity game. and as you can see i am using playerprefs

Comment: Okay, SharedPref and PlayerPref is the same. It saves the data locally in your android devices. What you need is online database

Comment: thanks for your reply, can't we store data in android device storage instead of temp memory as playerprefs do.?

Comment: Yes, you can. But, if you clear the data the storage will be cleared too. What you really need is online db that stored all of that data.

Comment: actually its a level games, so i dont need any online database, suppose if user will clear android storage then game will also remove and data of should also remove. Its very basic version of the game that's why i want to store levels that are unlocked remain unlocked.

Comment: You can go develop your own API on how to save it without doing online db. After that share it and let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

As UmarZaii said in the comments, if you manually delete your data... Then it is deleted. There is no way you can save data from your app on the user's device and then prevent the user from removing it. 
If what you want is a backup in case the user accidentally remove data or change it's phone, you can use online solutions.

Since you tagged "android", you can automatically store the data online using the user's play game account. Check google's [play games services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/). They have a [unity plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) that should allow you to easily login and save/retrieve game data